# C# Array.ConvertAll for compact framework

Tags: c#, arrays, compact-framework

As far as I know there is no `Array.ConvertAll()` for the .NET Compact Framework. What is the best way to do an `Array.ConvertAll()` in the CF?

```
public static string DataRowToString(DataRow dr)
{
    return dr["columns"].ToString();
}

public static string[] DataTableToArray(DataTable dt)
{
    var dr = dt.Select();
    string[] strArr = Array.ConvertAll(dr, new System.Converter<DataRow, string>(DataRowToString));
    return strArr;
}
```

The code above doesn't work in CF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a LINQ expression:

```
var result = input.Select(converter).ToArray();
```

Comment: +1 Cool, didn't know Compact Framework did Linq, had to actually look it up :)

Comment: I don't think linq would be prudent in this case since there would be 2 allocations for every object.

Comment: @Romoku: Why do you say that? And how is that a problem?

Comment: It is my understanding that the compact framework is aimed at embedded systems which require additional constringency when it comes to resource management.

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth: I've modified my question

Comment: @DanielHilgarth what does 'converter' stand for? Select() expects a filterExpression.

Comment: @Stacked: converter is that filter expression. This can be a lambda expression or a method like your `DataRowToString` method: `var result = dr.Select(DataRowToString).ToArray();`

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can use `reflector` to get at the implementation, which it turns out looks like this:

```
public static TOutput[] ConvertAll<TInput, TOutput>(TInput[] array, Converter<TInput, TOutput> converter)
{
    if (array == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("array");
    }

    if (converter == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("converter");
    }

    TOutput[] localArray = new TOutput[array.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        localArray[i] = converter(array[i]);
    }

    return localArray;
}
```

Comment: I hope it doesn't look like *exactly* like this... You know, telling someone to copy verbatim code from a copyrighted work...

Comment: @xanatos Sure it does work exactly like this. Have you never seen .Net code posted from Resharper? And also: Are you not aware that the Microsoft .Net source code is publicly available? http://referencesource.microsoft.com/

Comment: Yes, under the [Microsoft Reference Source License (MS-RSL)](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/referencesourcelicense.aspx) license for example, that gives you *(A) Copyright Grant- Subject to the terms of this license, the Licensor grants you a non-transferable, non-exclusive, worldwide, royalty-free copyright license to* **reproduce the software for reference use**

Comment: Honestly `Array.ConvertAll` isn't all that complicated to implement without viewing the source.

Answer (score 0):

When I have these problems, and I want to feel "clean", I normally watch what the good persons of [Project Mono](https://github.com/mono/mono/tree/master/mcs/class) did.

(I have my local copy, so I can look directly for `Array.cs`)... Now let's [see](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/corlib/System/Array.cs).

```
//
// System.Array.cs
//
// Authors:
//   Joe Shaw (joe@ximian.com)
//   Martin Baulig (martin@gnome.org)
//   Dietmar Maurer (dietmar@ximian.com)
//   Gonzalo Paniagua Javier (gonzalo@ximian.com)
//   Jeffrey Stedfast (fejj@novell.com)
//   Marek Safar (marek.safar@gmail.com)
//
// (C) 2001-2003 Ximian, Inc.  http://www.ximian.com
// Copyright (C) 2004-2011 Novell, Inc (http://www.novell.com)
// Copyright (C) 2011 Xamarin Inc (http://www.xamarin.com)
//
// Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining
// a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the
// "Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, including
// without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish,
// distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to
// permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to
// the following conditions:
// 
// The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be
// included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
// 
// THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND,
// EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF
// MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND
// NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE
// LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION
// OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION
// WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.

public static TOutput[] ConvertAll<TInput, TOutput> (TInput [] array, Converter<TInput, TOutput> converter)
{
    if (array == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException ("array");
    if (converter == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException ("converter");

    TOutput [] output = new TOutput [array.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i ++)
        output [i] = converter (array [i]);

    return output;
}
```

Because while the legality of looking at the .NET with reflector/ilspy is a gray area, copying verbatim the code is surely on the wrong side.

(note that I have added the copyright of the file, that alone is much bigger than the code :-), because technically if you want to use that little piece of code you'll have to respect its license, that is the MIT license)

Answer (score 0):

For .NET Core, this will be useful:

```
public static TOut[] ConvertAll<TIn, TOut>(this TIn[] thisArray, Func<TIn, TOut> converter)
{
    if (thisArray == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(thisArray));

    if (converter == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(converter));

    TOut[] revVal = new TOut[thisArray.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < thisArray.Length; i++)
        revVal[i] = converter(thisArray[i]);

    return revVal;
}
```